# SQL: Multiple Joins and WHERE statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tabled named 'users' a table named 'modules' and a table named 'users_modules'.

'users' contains 'user_id', 'first_name', 'last_name' and 'role'.

'modules' contains 'module_code' and 'module_title'.

'users_modules' contains 'user_id' and 'module_code'

The 'role' column in the 'users' table specifys if that user is a 'student', 'lecturer' or 'admin'.

I want to display to the user, which modules they are studying including the module code, module title and also the names of the lecturers of this module.

I have managed to right the following statement which gives me the 'module_code' and 'module_title' for all the module's a certain user is studying.

```
SELECT users_modules.user_id,
       users_modules.module_code,
       modules.module_title
  FROM users_modules
 INNER JOIN modules
    ON users_modules.module_code = modules.module_code
 WHERE user_id = 2;
```

I now need to display which lecturers are enrolled for this module. Needs to be part of the above statement as I am using it within a PHP while loop to produce a HTML table. I understand I need to do another JOIN for the users table so I can get the names of the lecturers but not sure how to finish writing the code.

The code will have to check which users are enrolled for the module (using the users_module table) and then see if any of them users have a 'role' (column in the users table) which equals either 'Lecturer' or 'Admin'.

---

Overview of what I want:

A result which shows a student (in this example a student with user_id=2) what modules they are enrolled in and what lecturers teach this module.

For everyone that has an involvement within this module (either teacher or student) will have a record in 'users_modules'.

I need a way to pull out of the 'users_modules' table the lecturers for each module, this is done by viewing the 'role' column in the users table.

Comment: Why does the 'users' table not have a 'user_id' field?

Comment: It does, my mistake when writing the question, will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should get you what you need, assuming your user table has a 'user_id' field. Also, note that it is always a good practice to alias your tables in your queries.

```
        SELECT u1.user_id AS 'Student ID', um1.module_code, m1.module_title,
        GROUP_CONCAT(u2.first_name) AS 'Lecturer First Name', 
        GROUP_CONCAT(u2.last_name) AS 'Lecturer Last Name'        
        FROM users u1 INNER JOIN users_modules um1 ON u1.user_id = um1.user_id
        INNER JOIN modules m1 ON um1.module_code = m1.module_code
        INNER JOIN users_modules um2 ON m1.module_code = um2.module_code
        INNER JOIN users u2 ON um2.user_id = u2.user_id
        WHERE u1.user_id = 2
        AND (u2.role = 'Lecturer' or u2.role = 'Admin')
        GROUP BY u1.user_id, um1.module_code, m1.module_title
        ;
```

Comment: @Jack Brown, Does this produce an output?

Comment: Hi @SS781, this currently gives me: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND (u2.role = 'Lecturer' or u2.role = 'Admin')' at line 1

Comment: There was just an extra semicolon, fixed now

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: I would tend to believe that there is something missing from the info you are giving if both my answer and that of @vp_arth are just returning for you empty sets.

Comment: WHERE um1.user_id = 2

The user with ID = 2, is a student not a lecturer or admin, cause this be causing the zero rows?

Comment: Ah yes that is probably right, let me try to re-shape query based on that.

Comment: Read the bottom part of my question I added to see if that helps, sorry for nay confusion but thanks for your time :)

Comment: Ok edited, see what this gets you. And meh, I'm kinda bored and lazy, so my time is not too valuable right now :)

Comment: Still zero rows :( and that is fair enough haha, I just want to try sort this out before going to sleep haha!

Comment: OK, another shot at it (it was still returning zero because of the issue from earlier)

Comment: This looks good so far and returns the correct output, let me add some more records to my database to test further give me 5 mins :)

Comment: Yes, seems to work well, look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b12f5a/3 I'm just trying to think of a way to fix where there is multiple lecturers for one module, instead of having two rows there can just be one row with multiple names under lecturer first name and lecturer last name

Comment: But I'm using this in PHP to create a HTML table so it's probably something I will need to do in PHP, thanks :)

Comment: It can be done in MySQL with GROUP_CONCAT(), trying to play around with it now actually

Comment: I have answer but I think it would be good to provide in different question.

Comment: Edited answer, should give you what you are looking for. Where my rep at? Holla

Comment: I'm at work so haven't checked the updated answer but I have up-voted you and marked yours as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add another join and necessary fields:

```
SELECT users_modules.user_id,
       users_modules.module_code,
       modules.module_title,
       users.first_name,
       users.last_name
  FROM users_modules
 INNER JOIN modules
    ON users_modules.module_code = modules.module_code
 INNER JOIN users
    ON user.user_id = users_modules.user_id
 WHERE users_modules.user_id = 2 AND users.role IN ('Lecturer', 'Admin');
```

Or with condition on join:

```
SELECT um.user_id,
       um.module_code,
       m.module_title,
       u.first_name,
       u.last_name
  FROM users_modules um
 INNER JOIN modules m
    ON um.module_code = m.module_code 
 INNER JOIN users u
    ON u.user_id = um.user_id
   AND u.role IN ('Lecturer', 'Admin')
 WHERE um.user_id = 2;
```

Comment: How can I only select the first_name and last_name of users which have a role of 'Lecturer' or 'Admin'?

Comment: @JackBrown, you can apply your conditions in `WHERE` clause and in the `ON` clause of `JOIN`. Select fields set is a simple enumerate what are you want in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Both of these return me with zero rows, I'm just trying to look through what you have provided to see if I can see what is wrong.

Comment: @JackBrown, look to it doesn't `what should I write`, but `how should I write`
It's very hard to me to understand, what exactly do you want...

Comment: try to remove `where` row

Comment: I have added a section to my question to try and clear what exactly I am trying to achieve, I hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple. If your modules always have lecturers add another INNER JOIN statement under the last join (and ON). The join will be on the module_code. If some modules don't have lecturers then LEFT JOIN instead otherwise rows will be removed that you may want to see.